# [Linux][mutt]How to improve email "trustworthyness"

Tags: linux, email, debian, html-email, mutt

So, I run an online service where people can sign up using their email address. It's as basic as it can get. Put in your address, receive email with confirmation link.

For that I've set up [mutt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutt_(email_client)) on Debian 11 which I'm using to send a HTML-EMail with an attachment.

For some reason, mail providers like googlemail and outlook filter those mails out. Sometimes they appear in peoples inbox, sometimes in spam and sometimes they don't get them at all. My googlemail UI shows me that it "couldn't verifiy if this email came from DOMAIN or from a spammer".

Does anyone here know what I can do to resolve this problem?

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: The keyword you are looking for is email deliverability. This is a massive area, kind of like asking "how do I make a website", which has nothing in particular to do with mutt or debian. So I expect this question should be closed unless you have a more particular question.

Comment: Alright, what can I do to prove to the Google Mailserver that my mails are actually coming from me?

Comment: You're going to get a much better answer googling this, since it's such an open question. Google "email deliverability", and you'll quickly come across configurations like SPF, DKIM (do them), and DMARC (if needed), spam laws (read about what you need to do like supply an 'unsubscribe'), server reputation, and so on. You may want to go down the route of latching onto a low cost high-reputation email server like Postmark.